# Changes of assembly global variable inside shared library not reflected from outside in C program in linux

Tags: c, linux, assembly, openssl, shared-libraries

I am going through the OpenSSL's basic assembly implementation of AES algorithm. Theoretically I know, AES uses 10 rounds when key length=128bits.
I need to verify programmatically . So I increased a global variable's (i.e. round_var) value by 1 every time one round of AES is completed. 
So at the end of AES operation on 1 block (16bytes), the variable's value will be 10 and at the end of AES operation on 2 block (2x16bytes), the variable's value will be 20.

Here is what I have done(aes-586.s),

; added global data declaration

```
.data
.global          round_var
round_var:
.long 0


_x86_AES_decrypt_compact:

; this is the AES round, where I increment global round_var by 1

.L004loop:
    .
    .
    .

;increase round_var by 1 

movl round_var, %eax
addl $1,%eax
movl %eax, round_var

.
.
.
jmp .L004loop
```

After that I build the Openssl successfully,

./config -g 386 shared --prefix=/usr

make

sudo make install

This the bash script through which I am performing decryptions 2000 x 1000 times just to make sure the program is running , not finished execution to reflect correct value of round_var.

```
cat run.sh


for i in `seq 1 1000`
do
/usr/bin/openssl enc -d -aes-128-ecb -in dummy_200.bin.enc -out dec-dummy_200.bin  -K A10BA778CBC2F2BDE3FB2C66F7F14FB6
done
```

This is the C program where I am printing the value of round_var.

```
//gcc dlsym_example.c -ldl

#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  void* lib=dlopen("/usr/lib/libcrypto.so",RTLD_NOW);

    long * func_addr =NULL;
    func_addr=(long *)dlsym(lib, "round_var");


    while(1)
    {
        if(func_addr !=NULL)
        { 
            printf("round_var %ld\n",*func_addr);

        }
    }    
return 0;
}
```

Surprisingly I am getting

```
round_var 0
round_var 0
round_var 0
```

I am expecting the changes of round_var should be reflected in C program.
BTW, inside gdb debug mode I crosscheck the value of round_var is incremented by 1 after every aes round that means logic of incrementing round_var is correct.

Where I am making mistakes ? Is it something related to visibility ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A shared library does not share everything between all processes that load it -- only of those pages/sections that can be shared (e.g. read-only, code...). In other words, you are getting a new instance of the global state of the library for each process that loads it.

Comment: @Acorn, if I put round_var in read-only section, then I can't modify/increment its value. However, when I put the round_var in data section then I can modify its value and its initial value is reflected . Initial value is reflected means, If I initialize round_var with 10, then from dlsym_example.c I am also getting 10. I am not getting its modified value during  aes operation.

Comment: Is there any other way of declaring round_var so that I can access that value ? Or, if I can declare a global function inside assembly code which return value of round_var  at that moment.

Comment: the value must live somewhere, i.e. some instance must be in memory. The shared libs are loaded per process as they need it (instancing their data section and then releasing it after process ends), so one option is to have some counter process running all the time, and use inter-process-communication from ssl to increment the counter, or you can atomically read-modify-write some file on disk, files are persisted, obviously.

Comment: @bholanath: The `.data` section is *not* shared -- you are getting a copy for each process, with the initial value you specified (otherwise, it would be in the `.bss` section). Global variables are "process-global", not "system-global".

Comment: thanks @Acorn for pointing correctly process global and system global.

Comment: I think one way to declare a shared memory inside assembly and then increment that shared variable inside assembly which will be visible from c program.

Comment: @bholanath: Not sure what you mean -- the easiest way is to call the OpenSSL library inside your C application. In other words, don't run `openssl` as a new process, but link with `libssl`.